# Case sensitivity in SELECT statements in MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

for example:

```
database username:       | textbox.text
Woods                    |  woods
```

i want to create an error if the input characters in textbox.text in vb.net must exactly the same value in database username.

```
here is my sample code in login:
 sqlcmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT uname FROM staff WHERE uname='" & textbox.Text & "'", connecthost)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do very much like what damienc88 did. The only thing I'd do different is not raise an error. If there is an exception however, return codes are greater than 0. So you'd want to be careful returning SQL errors as there will be an ambiguity between whether that was an error or rows returned.

Just return -1 if you don't find anything.

Plus SQL is case insensitive. So you don't need to worry about Woods or woods inside.

Comment: @Sheerwood John Caday, care to explain why the sudden change of the accepted answer after 6 months?

Answer (score 3):

You can use BINARY, check this:

```
SELECT *  FROM `table` WHERE BINARY `columnName` = 'x'
```

Try this:

```
sqlcmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT uname FROM staff WHERE BINARY uname='" & textbox.Text & "'", connecthost)
```

You can also use LOWER, check this:

```
SELECT uname FROM `staff` WHERE LOWER(`uname`) = LOWER('" & textbox.Text & "')
```

You can also use COLLATION, read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html)

Comment: Hi damienc88, what's wrong with my answer? care to read this? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

Comment: Do you try the BINARY? I would love to help you but please be specific with the details. :)

Comment: sir i already apply the BINARY and it work! hehe thank you sir JC Sneak!